# Responsive Design - Images not fitting viewport size height wise

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello I am new to responsive design and I have been recently working on a portfolio website where I have been trying to make it responsive at all the given sizes presented in the Mozilla responsive design developer view tool.

As I shrink the view port to go down to the smaller sizes the height of my images no longer fit the height of the view port, this can be especially seen at view port size 320px. Is this an issue with my media queries or a general flaw with my HTML structure? or CSS? Could this be an issue with the size of my images? This has derailed my progress with the other aspects of my website any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="typewriterscript.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img src="Header2.png" />
            </header>
            <div id="main-content">
                <img src="Aboutme2.png" />
                <div id="about-me"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <img src="Footer2.png" />
        </footer>
    </body>
    <!--<script LANGUAGE="javascript">
        startTyping(text, 50, "about-me");
    </script>-->

</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2576bc;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -81px;
}
header {
    width: 800px;
    height: 244px;
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#main-content {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
/*#about-me {
    position: absolute;
    width: 436px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #2576bc;
    border: solid 3px black;
    margin: -450px 180px;
}*/
footer, .push {
    height: 81px;
}
footer {
    width: 800px;
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
header img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
footer img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
#main-content img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Media Queries

```
/*Responsive CSS*/
 @media screen and (max-width:959px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #main-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    footer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .push {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #main-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    footer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .push {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 320px;
    }
    footer {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

Comment: By "viewport" do you mean the header tag and the "#main-content" div? If that is the case, it's because you arehave a fixed height of 244px and 500px respectively, so your images inside them are changing height, but their wrappers are staying the same height. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am using "viewport" to refer to the size of the device screen, but could the issue and solution you mentioned still be applicable? How would you suggest fixing this issue should I remove the height style's from the wrappers?

Comment: try, img { max-width: 100%; height:auto }, actually wait did you mean the image does fit in the wrapper? :/

Comment: Now I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but for starters, I would just set the header tag and #main-content to be height: auto.

Comment: Hi nCore I gave your suggestion a try, but no results. Thank you for your help! Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Sean Thompson, Ill try and clarify I apologize for the confusion. I'm asking how can I have my content i.e. header, footer, and main content fill up the entire size of a device screen at say 320px X 480px. As of right now at that size my images do not extend height wise to properly to fit the screen leaving gaps. Does this make more sense? The same happens at other sizes as well where there will be a gap between the main content and the footer.

Comment: Hmm ok. Makes sense. I'd recommend for mobile viewports using flexbox (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/) (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-css-flexbox-module--net-25655) That way you set a flexible horizontal or vertical layout that is fluid to your viewport.

Comment: What do you want? Do you want your images to fill their container's height and cut off the sides, or do you want the container to shrink so that your image can remain in the viewport at it's full width?

Comment: As far as I know the OP has the following choices: 1) maintain aspect ratio for width and no clipping = will not fill height of div, 2) maintain height to fill div = some form of clipping and/or overflow, 3) full width, full height = distorted image. Did I miss any?

Comment: So does the only solution to solve my issue without any loss of information involve me creating images for each different screen size that I want to support?

Answer (score 1):

The images are behaving like this, because the DIVs (and other elements—header, footer) they're enclosed in have a set height. Since the images are set to `width: 100%`, they will always fill the enclosing DIV in their width entirely. However, their height is set to `auto`, which means they will keep the original aspect ratio.

If you want the images to fill the DIV both height- and width-wise, don't set the height of the enclosing elements (that way the DIV will stretch around the images as needed).

Comment: I might be missing something but removing the `height` property won't cause the image to fill the full height of the containing DIV. If `height` is not explicitly set the default value is `auto`; so the OP's use of `height: auto;` would be redundant. The point about maintaining aspect ratio is spot on and is the inherent issue the OP is facing.

Comment: I'm talking about removing the height from the DIVs around images. That way they will adjust to the height of the images as needed..

Comment: Okay, original answer was a bit vague on that point and I see you have updated it to be more concise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You should use max-width on your #wrapper, and don't set manual heights on your div's. You don't need the media queries for this unless you want special styles for certain screen sizes.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2576bc;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 0;
}
#main-content {
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 0;
}
/*#about-me {
    position: absolute;
    width: 436px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #2576bc;
    border: solid 3px black;
    margin: -450px 180px;
}*/
footer {
    border: solid 4px black;
    margin: 0;
}
header img {
    width:100%;
}
footer img {
    width:100%;
}
#main-content img {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="typewriterscript.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img src="Header2.png" />
            </header>
            <div id="main-content">
                <img src="Aboutme2.png" />
                <div id="about-me"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <img src="Footer2.png" />
        </footer>
    </body>
    <!--<script LANGUAGE="javascript">
        startTyping(text, 50, "about-me");
    </script>-->

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are responsive.  If you try IE, Moz and Chrome you will see that they all perform a little differently as you shrink your window.  That difference is hard coded and nothing that I'm aware of can change that.

However, you might see if placing this first, in your CSS, doesn't help:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```